# how to get the string of the *xlsx file path name in Python？

Tags: python, excel, path

there are several different format files in the Documents

I need to get a string  which is the *xlsx format files path
I using below code ，but it return a error as like below

```
PATH= u'F:\Workfiles\周报\\forupdate'
filepath = os.path.join(PATH,str(os.listdir(PATH)))
```

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u"F:\Workfiles\\u5468\u62a5\forupdate\[u'suxl20170821.xlsx']"

does any body knows how to get the files path ？？？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  listdir to find the paths

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("F:\Workfiles\周报\forupdate"):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        print(os.path.join("F:\Workfiles\周报\forupdate", file))
```

or You can use glob

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("F:\Workfiles\周报\forupdate")
for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    print(file)
```

Comment: thanks method 1 is OK ，but method 2 seems os.chdir() have not work, it means  os have not change into the directory~~~